# Compactness of the trace operator in dimension 1

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators, trace-map

Let $T$ be the operator defined on the Sobolev space $H^1((0,1))$ by
$$T:H^1((0,1)) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}
\\ f \mapsto f(0).$$
This operator is clearly a finite rank operator and thus it is compact. Am I right?. Thank you.

Comment: If anything I would say you are more type than write

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Any $\Bbb R$-linear map to $\Bbb R$ has an image of dimension at most $1$, which means that the operator is of finite rank, which means that the operator is compact.